# Orthogonal projection onto a vector with matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

So I have this question here which says:

$a)$ Find the standard matrix of the linear operator $T:R^2\rightarrow R^2$ given by the orthogonal projection onto the vector $(1,-2)$.

$b)$ Given the linear transformation $T:R^2\rightarrow R^3$ such that

$$T(1,0)=(1,-2,3), T(1,1)=(0,1,4)$$

Find $T(2,3)$.

For part $a)$, I used my standard basis vectors to find the orthogonal projection. Thus, I went:

$T(e_1)=(1,0)-\frac{(1,0)\cdot(1,-2)}{\|(1,-2)\|}(1,-2)$
$=(\frac{4}{5},\frac{2}{5})$

Similarly, I get that $T(e_2)=(\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{5})$

So thus, my standard matrix is:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5}\\ 
\frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
    \end{array}
\right)
$

Apparently this isn't right. Why? Is there something I did wrong with my work?

For part $b)$, I know I need $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$ however, I only know what $T(1,0)$ is. Can I find $T(0,1)$ by going $T(1,1)-T(1,0)$?

Some guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: a) You're missing some minus signs, and the norm of the vector should be $\sqrt{5}$...

Comment: b) T(1,1) = T(1,0) + T(0,1), so work backwards

Comment: For part $b$, your reasoning is correct. For part $a$, I think the orthogonal projection does not require you to subtract from the original vector. The answer for the first basis vector is then just $\frac{(1,0) \cdot (1,-2)}{||(1,-2)||} (1,-2)$. Similarly for the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The projection of $v$ on the vector $w$ is $\displaystyle\frac{v.w}{\lVert w\rVert^2}w$. So, the projection of $(1,0)$ is $\displaystyle\left(\frac15,-\frac25\right)$ and the projection of $(0,1)$ is $\displaystyle\left(-\frac25,\frac45\right)$. So, the matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac15&-\frac25\\-\frac25&\frac45\end{bmatrix}.$$

b) Note that $(2,3)=3(1,1)-(1,0)$. Therefore, $T(2,3)=3T(1,1)-T(1,0)$.

Comment: Is there a reason I don't subtract for part a? I thought I had to subtract the parallel part off from the projection.

Comment: Why? With the operation defined like that, we don't even get a multiple of $(1,-2)$.

Comment: Ohh. I need to clarify. Does projection typically mean like orthogonal projection? I feel like I am missing what "Projection" means. Does that genrally refer to orthogonal projection?

Comment: No. A projection is a linear map $P$ from a vector space into itself such that $P\circ P=P$. But you mentioned orthogonal projection in the title.

Comment: Ohh i see. So because of the fact it mentions orthogonal projection, I can assume that the mapping is just orthogonal projection however in general, there is a parallel portion and a perpendicular portion in a projection. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “a parallel portion and a perpendicular portion”. If $P$ is a projection from a space $v$ onto a subspace $W$, then it is an orthogonal projection when, for each $v\in V$, $v-P(v)$ is orthogonal to each element ot $W$.

Comment: Here's a link to the clarification I was seeking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019431/clarification-of-projection

Answer (score 0):

The formula fir the orthogonal projection of $e_1$ along $(1,-2) $ as you have written is incorrect (a length should be squared, check).

In part two, since $T$ is linear, 
$T (0,1)=T ((1,1)-(1,0))=T (1,1)-T (1,0)$.